# solving resource linking error in Android studio

Tags: android

I am creating my first android studio app and I ran into this unusual error when I started adding more pages, it was building fine when I had one page (main activity), soon as I added a second activity it spiraled. Why is that and how can fix that?

[image]

Comment: Clean rebuild your project

Comment: Please insert your code and errors as text instead of or besides the image, there's a myriad of reasons why those should always be in the post as text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Go to your color.xml File and put this code

```
"<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>"
```

or

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like somewhere in your app you are making a reference to R.color.colorPrimary which does not exist in your colors.xml file.

Go to `res` folder -> `values` -> `colors.xml` and add `<color name="colorPrimary">#34617F</color>` (you can pick a new hex color of course :)